# Host key verification fails for a private git npm repository in jenkins

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, npm

we have a node project which uses some private bitbucket repositories as npm dependencies. These are added in our `package.json` as follows:

```
"errors": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[USER]/[REPO].git",
```

We have a jenkins build job which is defined with a `Jenkinsfile`. This file uses the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) to define a private ssh key which is used in the build job to pull the private repository as follows:

```
stage('Install dependencies') {
container('node-image') {
    sshagent(['degov-git']) {
        sh 'mkdir $HOME/.ssh && touch $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts && chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts'
        sh 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts'
        sh 'npm install'
    }
}
```

}

We, however, receive an error that the host key verification failed:

```
[2019-05-05T07:36:26.027Z] npm ERR! Error while executing:
[2019-05-05T07:36:26.027Z] npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[USER]/[REPO].git
[2019-05-05T07:36:26.027Z] npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
```

Is it possible to add the host key when using the sshagent in Jenkins? How would we go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. We ended integration the packages as git submodules for now.

Comment: i finally solved my problem, but i m not sure your and my context where identitcal.
I use ansible, and then i make a npm install with sub module from private repository.
Ansible execute npm command with sudo, but logged as normal user, whereas the ssh key and the host is not know by the logged user. I just copied and make right access on ssh key and known_hosts to the logged user. Dirty, but it made the job

Answer (score 0):

Likely, `bitbucket.org` has a number of public facing servers, so doing a keyscan on that single URI wouldn't work necessarily (when a different server is reached randomly). Also, the strategy of appending (`>>` instead of `>`) to the `known_hosts` file eventually will make a very large text file with duplicate, perhaps conflicting entries. [Cloudbees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000073552-Host-Key-Verification-for-SSH-Agents) discusses strategies to address the problem.

1. One solution might be changing the keyscan call to `ssh-keyscan -t ‘ssh-rsa,ssh-dss’ $AGENT_HOSTNAME_OR_IP` which collects additional keys. I'd also consider using `~` for the location of the `.ssh` directory instead of `$HOME` which I noted was different in a recent job being troubleshooted. Use `sh "printenv | sort"` to display exact values of current `ENVIRONMENT` variables in the job.
2. Another solution, perhaps not palatable, is to revert to the previous behavior of SSH Agent [until mid-2017](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-03-20/) where it set `StrictHostKeyChecking` off. (On a secured LAN with the Jenkins server and local Git server sitting next to each other -- perhaps over a private network -- this can be okay.) This is done by scrubbing and rewriting the `~/.ssh/config` file with something like `sh "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo 'Host *' > ~/.ssh/config && echo '    StrictHostKeyChecking no'`. I guess today I wouldn't do this over the open Web, but it's an option worth considering locally.

**NOTE:** Another common error in `sshagent` on Jenkins reports that `no user exists for uid` so `ssh` operations fail. A few versions ago the `SSH` agent updated an underlying library which now requires a provisioned user on the system. Similarly, this can be addressed with an approach similar to the [solution in this Jenkins ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47026?focusedCommentId=328779&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-328779).

Hopefully the information here finds others who might stumble upon this question as the first search result for related troubleshooting keywords.